# jQuery Datatables json AJAX help pls “No Data Available in Table”

Tags: c#, jquery, json, asp.net-mvc, datatables

I have a table that is made in the $( document ).readyfunction. I am also using the jQuery DataTables plugin. For some reason, when the page loads, the table loads but the first row says:

"No Data Available in Table".

**My controller:**

```
public string Lowx()
{
    var query = db.Infos.
            Include(x => x.Profile).
            Include(x => x.Cars).
            ToList();

    return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(query.ToList());
}
```

**My View:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <link href="~/Content/DataTables/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="~/Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="~/Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <title>Service</title>
</head>
<body>

    <p>
        <h1 align="center"> Сервис по обслуживанию автомобилей</h1>
        <ul id="nav">

        </ul>
        <a href='@Url.Action("Create")'><img src='/Content/addlow.png' width="40" height="40" /></a>
    </p>
    <table class="table" id="cars">
       <thead>
          <tr>
              <th>Имя</th> //firstname
              <th>Фамилия</th>  //lastname
              <th>Отчество</th> //middlename
              <th>День рождения</th> //birthday
              <th>Марка машины</th> //carname
              <th>гос.номер</th> //carnumber
           </tr>
       </thead>
    </table>


<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/DataTables/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function (data) {

          // Here is my datatable configuration
          $('#cars').DataTable({
              ajax: {
                  url: '@Url.Action("lowx")',
                  type: 'POST',
                  dataType: 'json',
                  dataSrc: ""

              },
              columns: [
                  { data: "FirstName", name: "FirstName" },
                  { data: "LastName", name: "LastName" },
                  { data: "MiddleName", name: "MiddleName" },
                  { data: "BirthDate", name: "BirthDate" },
                  { data: "CarName", name: "CarName" },
                  { data: "CarNumber", name: "CarNumber" },

              ],
        });
     });

 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/unuK2.jpg)

**Cannot figure out where the problem actually lies. Any help will be highly appreciated.**

**Thank you.**

Answer (score 0):

You have a `GET` controller method but in your datatable implementation you are using `POST` for ajax request.
Also, you can return `JsonResult` instead of `string` from your controller. That way MVC will take care of serialization of object and you don't have to do it explicitly.

**Controller**

```
public JsonResult Lowx()
{
    var query = db.Infos.
        Include(x => x.Profile).
        Include(x => x.Cars).
        ToList();

    return Json(query, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

And in your datatable code you can call it like

**jQuery**

```
$("#cars").DataTable({
  ajax: {
    url: '@Url.Action("Lowx")',
    dataSrc: ""
  },
  columns: [
    { data: "FirstName", name: "FirstName" },
    { data: "LastName", name: "LastName" },
    { data: "MiddleName", name: "MiddleName" },
    { data: "BirthDate", name: "BirthDate" },
    { data: "CarName", name: "CarName" },
    { data: "CarNumber", name: "CarNumber" }
  ]
});
```

Comment: It did not help

Comment: @АлександрПоляков I don't see any other problem here. Can you check that your query is returning any data? If it is showing the same "no data" message, there might not be any data in db.

Answer (score 0):

**Please try as follows:**

**In your controller:**

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Lowx()
{
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> LoadDataForDataTable()
{
   var draw = Request.Form.GetValues("draw").FirstOrDefault();
   var start = Request.Form.GetValues("start").FirstOrDefault();
   var length = Request.Form.GetValues("length").FirstOrDefault();

   ///Find sorting column name and order
   var sortColumnName = Request.Form.GetValues("columns[" + Request.Form.GetValues("order[0][column]").FirstOrDefault() + "][name]").FirstOrDefault();
   var sortColumnDir = Request.Form.GetValues("order[0][dir]").FirstOrDefault();


   int pageSize = length != null ? Convert.ToInt32(length) : 0;
   int skip = start != null ? Convert.ToInt32(start) : 0;
   int recordsTotal = 0;


    var query = db.Infos.
            Include(x => x.Profile).
            Include(x => x.Cars).AsQueryable();

    int recordsTotal = query.Count();

    //Sorting By Individual Column
    if (!(string.IsNullOrEmpty(sortColumnName) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(sortColumnDir)))
    {
       query = query.OrderBy(sortColumnName + " " + sortColumnDir);
    }

    int recordsFiltered = query.Count();

    var data = await query.Skip(skip).Take(pageSize).ToListAsync();
    return Json(new { draw = draw, recordsFiltered = recordsFiltered, recordsTotal = recordsTotal, data = data }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

**Then in the jQuery:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function (data) {
          // Here is my datatable configuration
          $('#cars').DataTable({
              ajax: {
                  url: '@Url.Action("LoadDataForDataTable")',
                  type: 'POST',
                  dataType: 'application/json',
              },
              columns: [
                  { data: "FirstName", name: "FirstName" },
                  { data: "LastName", name: "LastName" },
                  { data: "MiddleName", name: "MiddleName" },
                  { data: "BirthDate", name: "BirthDate" },
                  { data: "CarName", name: "CarName" },
                  { data: "CarNumber", name: "CarNumber" },

              ],
        });
     });

 </script>
```

Comment: It did not help

Comment: This is the way to implement jQuery Datatable with asp.net mvc. Check your other related codes please. check what error it actually showing and try to fix it. You can also share the error here too.

Comment: Didn't understand what you said. Please ask more details.